# "An Universal Etymological English Dictionary". Why "An Universal"?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, vowels

My question is not about the general usage of *a/an*, so, I believe, it is not a duplicate one.  It is specifically about the title of the dictionary **An Universal Etymological English Dictionary** compiled by Nathan Bailey.

[Nathan Biley's dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Universal_Etymological_English_Dictionary) is said to be first published in London in 1721. The etymology of the word *universal* (as per the [etymonline.com)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/universal#etymonline_v_4518) shows that the word has been in use centuries before the publication of the dictionary.

Now, the questions are:

> 1. Why is **an** used before the word universal /juːnɪˈvəːs(ə)l/ which begins with a consonant sound?
> 2. Has the word universal ever been pronounced with an initial vowel sound as /uːnɪˈvəːs(ə)l/?

Comment: Could it be that in 1721 English was pronounced differently in London than it currently is? Could it be that in 1721 written English followed different conventions than it does in 2019? Almost certainly. You will find many other oddities if you continue reading. Don't expect language rules to last indefinitely; they're always just compromises.

Comment: In the 1600s, *universal, unicorn, union, useful,* and so forth began with a diphthong—something like /iu/—rather than the consonant "y" (/j/ in IPA), so *an* was the correct article. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift). The sound was already changing by the 1700s, but language doesn't change all at once; some people still used *an universal* until around 1900.

Comment: @PeterShor, Thank you for the Wikipedia link which ultimately led me to *yod-dropping*, gave me a good read and where I found answer to my question.

Comment: @mahmud, care to answer your own question? Then you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regard to why Nathan Bailey might have been inclined to title his 1721 dictionary [*An Universal Etymological English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sM2uyrbP7CkC&pg=PP673&dq=%22pottage%22+%22potage%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5uaD34Yv5AhUJKUQIHUSoAII4KBDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22English%20Dicitonary%20comprehending%22%22&f=false), rather than *A Universal Etymological English Dictionary*, Peter Shor's explanatory comment, posted three years ago beneath the original question, seems quite plausible to a non-expert's ear (mine):

> In the 1600s, universal, unicorn, union, useful, and so forth began with a diphthong—something like /iu/—rather than the consonant "y" (/j/ in IPA), so an was the correct article. See [[the article on the Great Vowel Shift in] Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift). The sound was already changing by the 1700s, but language doesn't change all at once; some people still used an universal until around 1900.

Indeed, Bailey wasn't the first lexicographer to use the word "An Universal" in a dictionary title. That distinction goes to John Harris, [*Lexicon Technicum, Or, An Universal English Dictionary of Arts and Sciences*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TnNkAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT131&dq=%22large+Earthen+Pan+unglazed+in+a+great+Fire%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia_ZKXsenrAhVJgp4KHV0zCZoQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Lexicon%20Technicum%3A%20Or%22&f=false)  (1704). It also bears noticing that Bailey's publishing heirs and assigns were still using the title *An Universal Etymological English Dictionary* at least as late as the [twenty-third edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=lCw5AQAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&f=false#v=onepage&q&f=false) (1773).

It would be incorrect, however, to suppose that "an universal" was a universally accepted formulation in written English until the very late 1600s. It is quite clear, on the one hand, that the number of matches for "an universal" in the generally well-curated Early English Books Online database covering the period 1475–1700 is enormous: a total of 9,455 matches across 4,078 titles.

But on the other hand, a search of the same database for "a universal" over the same period yields a substantial number of matches as well: a total of 1,093 matches across 682 titles. In other words, during the sixteenth and seventeenth centuries (taken as a whole), "an universal" was about seven to nine times more common in print than "a universal." That is a large imbalance in favor of "an universal," but it is far from a unanimous one.

In examining the instances of "a universal" in the search results, I found instances from as early as 1641. From John Milton, "[Of Reformation Touching Chvrch-Discipline in England, and the Cavses That Hitherto Have Hindred It*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A34051.0001.001/1:4.1.4?ALLSELECTED=1;amt2=40;amt3=40;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div3;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=proximity;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=a+universal)" (1641):

> Look but a century lower in the 1. cap. of *Eusebius* 8. Book. What **a universal** tetter of impurity had invenom'd every part, order, and degree of the Church, to omit the lay herd which will be little regarded, *those that seem'd to be our Pastors*, saith he, *overturning the Law of Gods wor∣ship, burnt in contentions one towards another, and incresing in hatred and bitternes, outragiously sought to uphold Lordship, and command as it were a tyranny*.

Earlier in the same text, Milton uses the form "an universal," so the instance of "a universal" may have been a typographical error in this case. But other matches from the 1640s do not involve mixed usage. For example, from William Prynne, "[A Revindication of the Anoynting and Priviledges of Faithfull Subjects](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A91256.0001.001/1:2?ALLSELECTED=1;amt2=40;amt3=40;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=proximity;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=a+universal)" (1643) has only one instance of "universal," prefaced by "a':

> It is the observation of *Paulus Orosius, that when Christ the Prince of peace was born, the temple of Ianus was closed, & the whole world in peace without any wars, the better to entertain this Prince of peace*: O that this time of Christe nativity might produce such **a universal** peace throughout England, and the Christian world!

From John Knox, [*The Historie of the Reformation of the Church of Scotland*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A47584.0001.001/1:8?ALLSELECTED=1;amt2=40;amt3=40;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=proximity;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=a+universal) (1644), which again has only one instance of the term:

> The variety of matters that occurred, we omit, such as the order taken for keeping of the young Queen; of the provision for the mother; the calling home of the Douglas, and other, such as appertain to *a Universal* History of the time. For, as before we have said, we minde onely to follow the progresse of the Religion, and of the matters that cannot be severed from the same.

from Thomas Edwards, [*The First and Second Part of Gangræna, or, A Catalogue and Discovery of Many of the Errors, Heresies, Blasphemies and Pernicious Practices of the Sectaries of This Time*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A38109.0001.001/1:14.1?ALLSELECTED=1;amt2=40;amt3=40;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=proximity;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=a+universal) (1646), again a single instance:

> Now I do appeal to any man who knows *Cretensis*, either in his Writings or Preaching, whether he be not a man that speaks great swelling words of vanity; whether he doth not promise his followers liberty, yea, **a universal** liberty?

From Anthony Farindon, [*XXX Sermons Lately Preached at the Parish Church of Saint Mary Magdalen Milkstreet, London*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2?ALLSELECTED=1;amt2=40;amt3=40;c=eebo;c=eebo2;didno=A40891.0001.001;g=eebogroup;rgn=full+text;singlegenre=All;size=25;sort=datea;start=1;subview=detail;type=proximity;view=reslist;xc=1;q1=a+universal) (1647), which uses "an universal twice and "an universal once in a stretch of eight pages:

> And 1. he worketh in us **a universal** and equal obedience (for if he dwell in us, every room is his) ... He worketh I say **an universal**, equal obedience, which as a Circle, consists in an equality of life, in every respect answering to the command, and working of Christ, as a circle doth, in every part, look upon the point, or Center.
>
> ...
>
> Again, our [s]ense, and feeling of the operation of the spirit of Christ, by the practick efficacy of our knowledge, the actuation and quickning of our faith, and the power of it, working **a universal**, constant, sincere obedience, these are the chariots, which Christ sends to carry us out of Egypt, unto our celestial Canaan, and when we feel these, and by a sweet and well gained experience feel the power of them in our souls ...

From Wiliam Sedgwick, [*The Leaves of the Tree of Life: For the Healing of the Nations*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A92862.0001.001/1:1?ALLSELECTED=1;amt2=40;amt3=40;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=proximity;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=a+universal) (1648), which has "a universal" twice (including once in the title) and no instances of "an universal":

> *THE* LEAVES OF THE TREE OF LIFE: *For the healing of* THE NATIONS. Opening all the *wounds* of this kingdome, and of every party, and applying a *remedy* to them: By which we come to a right understanding between *King* and *Parliament*. **A universal** agreement and peace on all sides, and the *Kingdom* restored and setled upon a sure and unmoveable Foundation
>
> ...
>
> The Saviour of the People; thy *walls shall be called salvation, and thy gates praise*; sending forth *saving health* to the whole *Nation*, into every part that is pained or diseased: **a universal** remedy for all malladies; a skilfull *Physition*, rich∣y furnisht with *the fullnesse of the Spirit of* Christ to apply a plaster to every sore.

And finally, from William Bridge, [*The Works of William Bridge, Sometime Fellow of Emmanuel Colledge in Cambridge*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A77357.0001.001/1:4.1.2?ALLSELECTED=1;amt2=40;amt3=40;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div3;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=proximity;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=a+universal), volume 2 (1649):

> Though there be a communication of the Fulnesse of Christ unto all Beleevers: yet He does communicate as **a universal** Cause. The universall Cause doth seldom or never produce particular effects, but with a con∣currence of particular Causes. The Sun is the universal Cause of all the fruitfulnesse that is upon the earth: Yet notwithstanding, it does produce the Fruit, (your Corne, Barly, and Rye, and Wheat;) with the help of man: The ground is plowen, and sowen.
>
> ...
>
> The Sun does work with the Tree, when the Tree does bring forth fruit and yet 'tis not said that the Sun brings forth an apple, or brings forth fruit: because the Sun does work as **a universal** Cause, and the Tree as a particular Cause. So now, though Jesus Christ does work in all your workings; yet He is not said to Repent, or Beleeve, or to Obey; because He works as **a universal** Cause; and you work as a particular Cause ...

Overall, EEBO finds at least fifteen unique books published during the period 1641–1649 that contain instances of "a universal"—most of them without any countervailing instances of "an universal." This is a rather striking result, since EEBO finds no books from 1475–1640 that include even a single instance of "a universal." The flurry of instances in the 1640s, followed by increasing numbers of instances in the remaining decades of the seventeenth century, suggests that the pronunciation of *universal* among some groups of English speakers may have begun to change significantly by the middle decades of the 1600s.

"A universal" probably remained less common that "an universal" throughout the latter half of the seventeenth century—although I don't know of a simple but reasonably rigorous way to confirm that, since there are too many matches for "an universal" in both EEBO and EEBO2 to permit automated sorting of the search matches by date. Even so, the rise of "a universal" as an alternative spelling to "an universal" (which in turn suggests the emergence of a different pronunciation of "universal") seems to have its origins in the 1640s.